# How to assume user that started a GitHub Action?

Tags: github-actions

I’m maintaining a GitHub Action that [creates branches from issues](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch). A common usage pattern is that multiple developers in a single repository interact with this action by giving it ChatOps commands in issue comments.

My problem: The action needs to interact with the repository as the user that activated it (for example when a new pull-request is created).

Currently all activities from the action are done under the `github-actions [bot]` account.
I’m aware of the option to inject a Personal Access Token (PAT) into the action but this would make all the activities originate from the account that the PAT belongs to.

See [this](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch/issues/80#issuecomment-760767236) and [this](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch/issues/329) issue for the type of problems users of my action run into.

Answer (score 0):

The information is available in the `github` context under `github.actor`. Then to impersonate the user during the creation of the branch/pr it doesn't seem possible. In your specific situation, I think, taking the `github.actor` and adding it as a reviewer of the PR or adding something like `created by Username` in the body of the PR is probably a better idea.

Comment: The problem remains how to assume that user. For example, I already know which user activated the action from the payload information but I need to open a PR as that user. Currently I make an empty commit using the username from the payload but that doesn't work for repositories that require signatures: https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch/issues/338

Comment: @RobvanderLeek as I mentioned, it doesn't seem to be possible, not with the REST API at least.